# WPF Grid columns width on auto but stretched

Tags: wpf

In my application, I have at the bottom of my window up to 4 texts that display some information. I do not know the contents of these texts up until runtime and I don't know if there is zero or up to 4. There is never more than 4.

[image]

The problem is as you can see in the picture is that the 3rd text overflows. Now, this is because the implementation of this at the moment is a uniform grid in a items control:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" Height="20" ItemsSource="{Binding VersionInfoItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ess:VersionInformation}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="viGroup"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3 0 5 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="0 0 4 0"><Run Text=":"/></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

So I tried to create a test with a grid setting all column definitions to Auto, but that just makes them all stack up in one side:

[image]

I would like them to do this:

[image]

Is it possible to configure a grid or a uniform grid to achieve this (or should I use a different control), or must this be done in the code-behind and somehow analyze which areas are overflowing and then correct the widths to accommodate the texts?

I have tried to apply stretch to the width of the contents, but that had no effect. I also found an article talking about overriding uniform grid column definitions, but since I only know the content and the number of them at runtime, this was not applicable.

**Solution (Based on Mikes answer):**

Mike suggenstion got me on the right track and I made it work so it can handle any number of texts i might get:

[image]

[image]

What I did was i added two converters that either returns Double.NaN for auto or new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Star); for star columns. I then switch from a collection to specific object that i set and then bind those botht to the column difinitions and the textblocks:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Vi1, Converter={StaticResource StarConverter}}"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Vi1, Converter={StaticResource AutoConverter}}"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Vi2, Converter={StaticResource StarConverter}}"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Vi2, Converter={StaticResource AutoConverter}}"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Vi3, Converter={StaticResource StarConverter}}"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Vi3, Converter={StaticResource AutoConverter}}"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Vi4, Converter={StaticResource StarConverter}}"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Vi4, Converter={StaticResource AutoConverter}}"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3 0 5 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Vi1.Key}"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="0 0 4 0"><Run Text=":"/></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Vi1.Value}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3 0 5 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="3">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Vi2.Key}"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="0 0 4 0"><Run Text=":"/></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Vi2.Value}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3 0 5 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="5">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Vi3.Key}"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="0 0 4 0"><Run Text=":"/></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Vi3.Value}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3 0 5 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="7">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Vi4.Key}"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="0 0 4 0"><Run Text=":"/></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Vi4.Value}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

So if my Vi object is set, the corrospnding column difinitions gets an Auto or a Star width. If it is not set, both gets 0. Here are the converters for good measure:

```
//Star converter
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if(value != null)
        return new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Star);
    return 0;
}

//Auto converter
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value != null)
        return Double.NaN;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you are looking for, but I suppose that you'd like to have uniform spaces between your labels. A quick and dirty trick that comes to my mind requires adding empty columns (of width *star*) between your labels, like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Text1: longer text" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="Text2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Text="Very very extremly long text that gets clipped, or not" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="7"  Text="Text3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

This code gets you following results (depending on the text length in the labels):

[image]
[image]

Let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: That is a neat trick. It solves the overflow issue really well, however it will not handle if for instance I only get 2 texts instead of 4. All though I do have an idea to control the widths of the columns via a converter to set it to 0, if there is no text to display. That way it might automate this with out an issue.

Comment: It worked with some tweaking, added solution to question